# C# DataGrid filled with Lists with multiple layers

Tags: c#, wpf, list, binding, datagrid

I've been stuck on this for days now and just can't find a solution on my own. I am trying to fill a DataGrid with a `List<Plants>` as an ItemsSource. The problem is, the type `Plant` has a member of type `ICollection<PlantType>` for which I need to display in a corresponding column of the DataGrid as a string where each item in the ICollection is on a new line like this:

```
"Type1, \n Type2, \n ..."
```

I'll show the simplified code here (copying the whole code would overdo it a little).

```
public partial class Plants
{
    public Plants()
    {
        PlantType = new HashSet<PlantType>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PlantType> PlantType { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `PlantType` has the `Type` column (not `Plant`). Now I want to fill a DataGrid with this information so ideally it'll look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
|  Name   |    Page    |     Type       |
|---------------------------------------|
| plant1  |    3       | supporting     |
|---------------------------------------|
| pla2    |    13      | not-supporting |
|---------------------------------------|
|         |            | test           |
|---------------------------------------| 
|         |            | also this type |
|---------------------------------------|
|         |            | type           |
|---------------------------------------|
| plantZ  |    40      | test           |
-----------------------------------------
```

The problem at the moment is, it only fills in the name and page (since those are not HashSets and therefore clear). This is how my code for filling the DataGrid looks:

```
private void BuildDataGridContent(List<Plants> lList) 
{
    dataGrid.IsReadOnly = true;
    dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = lList;

    DataGridTextColumn textColumn1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn3 = new DataGridTextColumn();

    textColumn1.Header = "Name";
    textColumn1.Binding = new Binding("Name");
    textColumn2.Header = "Page";
    textColumn2.Binding = new Binding("Page");
    textColumn3.Header = "Type";
    textColumn3.Binding = new Binding("Type");  // <-- the problem is here. It can't directly access lList.PlantType.Type (PlantType = Table name; Type = column name in the SQL DB)

    dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn1);
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn2);
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn3);
}
```

I've tried things but have run out of ideas and google search terms. Can someone tell me how I correctly bind the `Type` to the Column this way?

Comment: Your example of the view you desire is a bit unclear. Are you saying there should be a row for each `Plant` instance followed by a row for each `PlantType` Instance in the respective `ICollection<PlantType>`?

Comment: Yeah it's a little unclear, sorry. I mean, the Types should be listed in the same row as the initial plant, but seperated by a comma and a line break. In the example "test", "also this type" and "type" would be in the same row as "not supporting" (all are part of name: pla2) but in a listed form.

To make it more clear:  Plantname | page | planttype (listed, since there can be more than one at a time)

Comment: I would create a `PlantViewModel` class that has a property like `Type` of type string along with the same properties `Name` and `Page`. Then I would just map `Plant` to `PlantViewModel` and finally bind to PlantViewModels instead.

Comment: Oh thanks soo much! It's so simple, yet I just couldn't get this idea on my own. Thanks it works now!! :)
Do you want to post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as helpful?

Comment: Done... Also see [C# Coding Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx). `buildDataGridContent` should really be capitalized.

Comment: Thanks, must have picked that up wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonably simple solution might be to just introduce a `PlantViewModel` type for binding to each DataGrid row rather than binding directly to your data model type (`Plant`). This of course requires redefining some properties in the view model that are also in the data model plus introducing mapping logic from `Plant` to `PlantViewModel` and potentially the other way around (if your view is editable) but it promotes loose coupling between data model and view.